# Very bad Eevee viewport performance on Macbook Pro 2018 (Blender 2.8)

Tags: hardware

I’d like to ask you guys about an advice.

The problem is: ultra bad Eevee performance on:
Macbook Pro 15" 2018
2,2 GHz Intel Core i7
16 GB Ram
Radeon Pro 555X 4GB

As soon as I run Eevee viewport I got very bad performance, I’m even not sure if my macbook starts to kick in his graphic card. I know that macbooks aren’t for 3D graphics, BUT… Blender works quite good on previous generation, the one that I was testing is:

Macbook Pro 13" 2015
2,9 GHz Intel Core i5
16 GB Ram
And no graphic card (only integrated Iris Graphics 6100 1536 GB

Here’s a video comparison, made on the the same project, so lighting and render settings are the same.

[-> Video comparison <-](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNs_MlbIYp8)

Do you have any ideas? I'm using Blender 2.8

Comment: Same here... Awaiting for any feedback to this issue.
According to the latest youtube video of Blender official meeting. I noticed that they are using a MBP... which is even the old model. I'm not sure if it's because the old MBPs are using NVIDIA. But the MBP 2018 is Radeon...
Hope the develop team would notice this and do something about it in the future version.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I still haven't managed to find any solutions for now. Let's just hope that it will be fixed.

Comment: Are there any news on this? Still having the issue with Blender 2.81 and Macbook Pro 2019.